# How many strings with seven characters can be formed from the letters in EVERGREEN?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many strings with seven characters can be
formed from the letters in EVERGREEN?

---

I can see the 7 character words such as

$EEEEVGN$,

$EEEERR(V/G/N)$

$RRVGNEE$

$EEERR(VG/VN/GN)$

$EEEVGNR$

$EEEE(RGN/RGV/RVN)$

---

Is there any other general or formulatic procedure to know how many of these patterns are there ?

Comment: hint : the E's are indistinguishable as are the R's.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Sorry, didn't get you .

Comment: try 7! ways to order all the letters then ... that's a hint, how many of these are the same ?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the number of arrangements using the seven letters EEEEGNV?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, I know that.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I am confused how to know how many such patterns are possible so that no such pattern is missed .

Comment: there are 9 letters in evergreen take 7 of them ( there are a number of ways of doing this) divide out by the factorial of how many of each letter there are.  sum the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider cases based on the number of E's and the number of R's that appear in a given word.

Since EVERGREEN has nine letters, we must use $2$, $3$, or $4$ E's in order to create a word with seven letters.

Two E's:  If we use two E's, we must use all of the remaining letters.  Choose two of the seven positions for the E's, two of the remaining five positions for the R's, then arrange the three single letters in the remaining three spots.
$$\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}3! = \frac{7!}{2!5!} \cdot \frac{5!}{2!3!} \cdot 3! = \frac{7!}{2!2!}$$

Three E's:  If we use three E's, we can use either one or two R's.

If we use three E's and two R's, we must choose three of the seven positions for the E's and two of the remaining four positions for the R's.  Since we cannot use another E, we have three choices for the leftmost open position and two choices for the final open position.

> $$\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2} \cdot 3 \cdot 2$$

If we use three E's and one R, we must use all of the other letters once.  We choose three of the seven positions for the E's.  We then arrange the four single letters.

> $$\binom{7}{3} \cdot 4!$$

Four E's:  If we use four E's, we can use $0$, $1$, or $2$ R's.  Can you continue?